# Collective Success over Individual Action

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase that captures the essence of collective success (as a group or team) over the action or accomplishment of individuals? Could be something borrowed in English from other languages?

Please cite all your responses

Answer (score 0):

When multiple entities work together to achieve something, there is **synergy**.

> [synergy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synergy) (n) - the increased effectiveness that results when two or more people or businesses work together; a mutually advantageous conjunction or compatibility of distinct business participants or elements (as resources or efforts)

You may also say that there is a  **team effort**, but that doesn't necessarily suggest a success or accomplishment.